# SQL does table partitioning automatically partition indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When partitioning a table, do the indexes (both non-clustered and clustered) get partitioned automatically or do I need to align them manually? Is a recreate required to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Table partitioning should be renamed to "index partitioning" since partitioning the table is actually partitioning the clustered index. (When partitioning a heap SQL Server creates a kind of logical index.)

This means You have to manually setup partitioning for all other indexes. Recreating the indexes is the way to go for moving them to a partitioning scheme.